# ng formatting a table

Tags: angular, html, html-table

I'm trying to format a table in Angular.
I have a DB with First name, Last name, City, Country.
I'm trying to display the data in a table format.
Here is my code:

```html
<table border="1" style="width:70%">
  <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
    <th style="width:20%">Last Name</th>
    <th style="width:20%">First Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%">Street</th>
    <th style="width:20%">City</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody>
    <span *ngFor="let i of x">
      <tr>
        <td>{{i.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{i.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{i.address.street}}</td>
        <td>{{i.address.city}}</td>
      </tr>
    </span>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

All the table fields are displayed under the "Last name" column.

Attached is a picture of how my table looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `span`, it does not belong in a table (except within a cell). Put the ngFor into the `tr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table border="1" style="width:70%">


    <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
          <th style="width:20%">Last Name</th>
          <th style="width:20%">First Name</th>
          <th style="width:40%">Street</th>
          <th style="width:20%">City</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>



  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fuller</td>
      <td>Andrew</td>
      <td>908 W. Capital Way</td>
      <td>Tacoma</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Fuller</td>
      <td>Andrew</td>
      <td>908 W. Capital Way</td>
      <td>Tacoma</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Fuller</td>
      <td>Andrew</td>
      <td>908 W. Capital Way</td>
      <td>Tacoma</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Fuller</td>
      <td>Andrew</td>
      <td>908 W. Capital Way</td>
      <td>Tacoma</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Don't wrap `<tr>` in `<span>` tag, you can use `<span>` inside `<td>`.

Run for loop on `<tr>` of `<tbody>`.

Let me know if you still face issue.

Comment: Hi, the span is for the Angular loop. The loop gets the data from a json structure. If I don't have the span I don't have a place to put the loop in.

Comment: Did you read my answer? You don't need the span, the loop belongs on the `tr`.